# Use a wildcard ssl cert to sign other certs

Tags: subdomain, ssl-certificate, wildcard

Is it possible to use a wildcard SSL certificate to sign other certificates?

i.e. I have bought a root signed wildcard certificate for *.example.com

I want to allow a third party to provide a service for me, on thirdparty.example.com.

Is it possible for me to create a certificate for thirdparty.example.com and sign it using my *.example.com cert? Or do I have to buy a separate cert for the third party.

If this is not possible, is it possible to buy a domain-signing-cert? Just to be clear, I only want to sign certs for *.example.com, not a root level (*.com) signing cert.

Comment: This question looks very similar to: http://serverfault.com/q/274852/149956

Answer (score 6):

No, you can't (although it is technically possible, but it won't work). Because certificate signing certificate must have two extensions with the following values:

1. **Basic Constraints** must be set to **CA=True** and be marked as critical
2. **KeyUsages** extension must have a **keyCertSign** and **cRLSign** bits enabled.

> is it possible to buy a domain-signing-cert?

yes, it is possible, but it would be very expensive for you (if you don't plan to issue a large number of certificates). Because you will have to pay a huge price for this service, buy required hardware (HSM is mandatory), write documentation (CPS at a minumum) and process external audits to verify whether you comply with provider's CPS (certificate practice statement). Several time ago I wrote an article about root certificate signing: [Certification Authority Root Signing](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/5973.certification-authority-root-signing.aspx).

HTH

Comment: The link is to an extension for TLS certs which allows it to be restricted to only certain domains. Here is a question identical to mine, with a correct answer: https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/31376/can-i-restrict-a-certification-authority-to-signing-certain-domains-only Your answer is still technically correct, but it is actually possible for a CA to sell a CA signing cert which is limited to a specific domain - it may need a change of regulation, but this CA signing cert would not need to be protected as strongly as a full CA cert

Comment: It still must be protected like any other CA certificate. Not sure how NC extension is going to update my answer.

Comment: Yes, at the moment, it must. But it's far less of a problem if a restricted CA certificate escapes. So, they could change the regulations for CA certs which are restricted. You didn't mention anything about the NC extension in your answer, white was exactly what I asked for. The only issue is the regulations

Comment: There are other issues and NC is still not much relevant to this thread. CAs won't change qualified CA requirements regardless of NC presence or absence. And be aware that NC is not supported by certain clients, so NC may not be acceptable.

Comment: How is NC not relevant? I just told you that the other question was a duplicate of mine and has the correct answer?

Comment: These are distinct questions. NC is correct for the other thread you mentioned. But for this thread it is not that significant.

Comment: My answer is correct in the context of this thread (yes, I'm aware you are the OP).